# How do I write lambda expression which rethrows checked exception without using try {} catch {} block?

Tags: java, exception, lambda, try-catch

I have a lambda expression, which can throw a `IOException`:

```
    Function<String, List<String>> readFile = path-> {
        try {
            return Files.readAllLines(
                    Paths.get((String) path), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    };
```

I would like to write the same lambda expression without using the `try {} catch {}` block, so that the exception would be rethrown to the enclosing function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Function<String, List<String>> readFile = path-> {
        try {
            return Files.readAllLines(
                    Paths.get((String) path), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return null;
        }
    };
}
```

The only problem is that **I cannot define my own interfaces/classes** and I can only use interfaces provided by Java APIs.

Would that be possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rethrow the excepion, you can use RuntimeException. 
Add this to your catch body.

```
throw new RuntimeException(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `Function.apply` does not throw checked exceptions, you cannot do it ...

... in a legal way. However, you can consider "sneaky throw" if you can take the risk

```
interface FunctionX<T,R, X extends Exception> extends Function<T,R>
{
    R applyX(T t) throws X;

    @Override
    default R apply(T t)
    {
        try
        {
            return applyX(t);
        } 
        catch (Exception x)
        {
            throw Util.sneakyThrow(x);
        }
    }

    public static <T,R,X extends Exception> 
    FunctionX<T,R,X> of(FunctionX<T,R,X> f){ return f; }

}

// Util.java

public static RuntimeException sneakyThrow(Throwable t)
{
    throw Util.<RuntimeException>sneakyThrow0(t);
}
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private static <T extends Throwable> T sneakyThrow0(Throwable t) throws T
{
    throw (T)t;
}
```

Usage example

```
    Function<String, List<String>> readFile = FunctionX.of( path-> {
        return Files.readAllLines(
            Paths.get(path), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    } );

    readFile.apply("/no-file");
```

Comment: It still will be defining new interface, which I want to avoid.

Comment: you use it as Function.